# Add multiple characters to a string at random positions using substr_replace()

Tags: php

I want to add "+" character to a string "donalddukeoflagos" multiple times at random positions.

Donalddukeoflagos will now be don+alddu+ke+ofl+agos

The code below is working very well, but it can only add one character at a time.

```
<?php
$mailad = "Donalddukeoflagos";
$length = (strlen($mailad) - 1);
$insertposition = rand(1,$length);
echo substr_replace($mailad,"+",$insertposition,0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a loop.

```
$specialCharacterCount = 5;
$mailad = "Donalddukeoflagos";
for ($specialCharacterIndex = 0; $specialCharacterIndex < specialCharacterCount; specialCharacterIndex++) {
  $length = (strlen($mailad) - 1);
  $insertposition = rand(1,$length);
  echo substr_replace($mailad,"+",$insertposition,0);
}
```

Comment: nice approach, but your code also repeats donalddukeoflagos 5 times